# Significato di "stacco di vita" e "stacco di coscia"

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Ferito a morte*, di Raffaele La Capria, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Bionda e longilinea, bel contrasto, tra quei due. Arrivano così sull’altra terrazza. La discussione sul Venezuela si ferma di botto, e tutti a guardare Betty Borgstrom con lo slip quattro dita sotto l’ombelico, i reni sottili, lo **stacco di vita**, che classe! si vede da come cammina, una vera novità – tutti, tranne Glauco che volta le spalle di proposito, ma tanto chi lo nota?, per non dare soddisfazione, e si finge interessatissimo a quelli che giocano sulla spiaggia.

Ho letto tutte le accezioni che si trovano nella [voce "stacco" sul vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/stacco1) e su altri dizionari, ma non riesco a capire il senso dell'espressione "stacco di vita". Fa forse riferimento a questa definizione?

> Con altro uso fig., rilievo, risalto, spicco, soprattutto nell’espressione *fare stacco*.

Vuol dire che la cintura di questa ragazza faceva spicco, attirava l'attenzione?
Me lo potreste spiegare, per favore?

Aggiungo che, ricercando questa espressione su Google, ho trovato alcune occorrenze.

Inoltre, nei commenti alla domanda si è menzionato che un'espressione usata più spesso è "stacco di coscia". Potreste spiegare anche cosa significa?

Comment: Penso si riferisca al fatto che la ragazza ha la vita sottile, che “stacca” la parte superiore del corpo da quella inferiore,   valorizzandole. https://i0.wp.com/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/cmu30claudio-content/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/04155604/ClioMakeUp-snellire-il-punto-vita-abbigliamento-pantaloni-gonna-vestito-giacca-cappotto-outfit-21.jpg?resize=533%2C800&ssl=1

Comment: Non ho tempo per scrivere una risposta, ma si può trovare qui: http://www.gdli.it/sala-lettura/vol/20?seq=36 Si sente parlare più spesso dello “stacco di coscia” per indicare appunto una coscia (femminile) che risalta per lunghezza e bellezza.

Comment: Ah, grazie, @DaG: di solito guardo il GDLI, ma questa volta, non so perché, non l'ho fatto. Tuttavia, in quest'altra espressione, "stacco di coscia", il senso di "staccare" sembra un po' diverso, no?

Comment: Ho aggiunto alla domanda l'espressione menzionata da @DaG perché così mi sembra più utile per le persone che, come me, non conoscono queste locuzioni. Spero che qualcuno possa scrivere una risposta usando la informazione dal GDLI che si trova nel link del commento di DaG.

Answer (score 2):

Secondo il [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000036.jpg),
che cita appunto il brano di La Capria riportato nella domanda, la locuzione *stacco di vita* ha il significato seguente:

> assottigliamento del corpo in corri­spondenza dei fianchi.

Come spiegato da @DaG nel suo commento, *stacco di coscia* si usa per indicare una coscia (femminile) che risalta per lunghezza e bellezza.

Comment: Ho preso dal tuo commento, @DaG, e ho scritto questa risposta che ho fatto community-wiki, in modo che possa essere migliorata da te o da qualsiasi altro utente. Fare questo mi sembra meglio che avere un'altra domanda senza risposta.

Comment: Se qualcuno decide di scrivere una risposta alternativa, questo post può essere cancellato.